# How to make UI suitable for any screen size

Tags: unity-game-engine

I pretty much have a uniqe UI design about the image in the middle which I want to resize. Now it works for any 1080p height value. However, both the image itself and the children of it gets cursed in case of a resize in height.

[2560x1440, I want the children of the image to get resized according to the size of the image (the white background for the buttons named background) and I want the image itself to expend horizontally so that it looks nice.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qs702.png)

[1280x720, I want the buttons to get smaller so that they fit to the background and look nice.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3tz7.png)

[1920x1080, this is the only one with appropirate sizes. I want all of the resulations to look similar to this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGknc.png)

I have checked multiple tutorials and saw nothing that would fix my problem. I would like to hear any possible solitions to this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add a canvas scaler to your Canvas, and set it to 'Scale by size'.

You may wanna use a separate prefab for the 1280x720 resolution though.

Comment: I can't edit apparently because StackOverflow is too busy.. I meant scale by height.